# Magento2 : how to load and execute third party .js

Tags: magento2, javascript

In a module I would like to use three.js in a block .phtml

I then tried the following way to use thrid party js :
[link](https://www.siphor.com/magento-2-requirejs/)

(the first example with custom.js)

It works fine. I then added three.js in requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            custom: "Vendor_Module/js/custom/custom",
            three: "Vendor_Module/js/three/build/three"
        }

    }
};
```

and in my phtml file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['custom','three'],function(custom,three){
        alert(custom.message);
    });
</script>
```

the reference to three is working, but How can I execute it and access the vars it generates (like for example THREE)?

Here is the link to three.js source code : [source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/build/three.js)

Thank you for your help,

EDIT 1 :

.phtml file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['custom','three'],function(custom,three){
        alert(custom.message);
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var mesh;
        init();
        function init() {
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 400;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'textures/crate.gif' );
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            //
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }
    });
</script>
```

generates THREE is not defined error

EDIT 2 (updated):

full three.js example

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['custom','three'],function(custom,THREE){

        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var mesh;
        init(THREE);
        animate();
        });

        function init(THREE) {
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 400;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/textures/crate.gif'); ?>" );
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            //
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }
        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
            mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }

</script>
</div>
```

EDIT3:

I would like now to add ThreeCSG.js

I updated requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            three: "Vendor_Module/js/three/build/three",
            threecsg: "Vendor_Module/js/ThreeCSG/ThreeCSG"
        },
    }
};
```

and try to make :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['three','threecsg'],function(THREE){
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var mesh;
    init(THREE);
    render();
    //animate();
    }); 
    function init(THREE) {

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
        camera.position.z = 20;
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        ...
        mesh=createCSG(THREE);
        ...
    }

    function createCSG(THREE) {
        var geometry1 = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 100, 100, 2 );
        var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 10, 10, 2 );
        var material1 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0x111111, roughness: 0.1, metalness: 0.4, side: THREE.DoubleSide});

        var geometry1_csg=new ThreeBSP(geometry1);
        var geometry2_csg=new ThreeBSP(geometry2);
        var res=geometry1_csg.substract(geometry2_csg);
        var result=res.toMesh(material1);

        return result;
    }
</script>
```

But I have an error:

> THREE is not defined in ThreeCSG.js

(Link to ThreeCSG.Js : [here](https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG/blob/master/ThreeCSG.js))

Comment: You can use as three.extractRotation(), three.makeRotationFromEuler()

Comment: please let me know if you have issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with below code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['custom','three'],function(custom,THREE){
        alert(custom.message);
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var mesh;
        init(THREE);
    });

        function init(THREE) {
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 400;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'textures/crate.gif' );
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            //
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }
</script>
```

Comment: seems to load, but the full three.js example does not work (EDIT2)

Comment: you need to keep function outside of requirejs as per above answer.

Comment: Hi Rakesh. If you are still there, could you please have a look at my Edit3 please?