# Non - AMD Module - JSPDF - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, third-party-module

We are trying to implement JSPDF on our product pages.  We have created a module to load the JS on these pages but we are coming up short.  We are getting constructor errors or not defined errors based on variations on implementation.

We have tried the following:
[How to add JS library to Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237275/how-to-add-js-library-to-magento-2)

Currently we have this deployed unsuccessfully and are interested in learning what we can do to resolve the constructor errors and begin using JSPDF within our magento 2 installation.

> app/code/VENDOR/JSpdf/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config ={
paths:{
    'jSpdf': 'VENDOR_JSpdf/js/jspdf.min'
},
shim:{
    jSpdf :{
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
};
```

> app/code/VENDOR/JSpdf/view/frontend/templates/jspdf_index_index.phtml

```
<div class="button-click">Run Code!!!</div>
<div id="content">
    <h1>  
        Page Heading - Nothing More To See Here
    </h1>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'jSpdf'],function($, ui, jsPDF){
    $('.button-click').on('click', function(){
        console.log('click triggered');
        pdf();
    });
});

function pdf(jsPDF){    
    const pdf = new jsPDF(); 
    pdf.text(10, 40, Order); pdf.save('order.pdf');
    console.log('function triggered');
}

</script>
```

The reason for defining the pdf function outside of require is found and outlined here:
[Magento2 : how to load and execute third party .js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200548/magento2-how-to-load-and-execute-third-party-js)

Also this is another resource which we found useful but could not implement
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9602

Any advice on mixing non AMD and AMD modules within Magento 2 would be very welcomed.